# How to Convert now() into an Oracle to_date function?

Tags: mule, dataweave

i am getting the field in payload as 2021-04-05T16:49:03.693-04:00 , which is a

```
now() as LocalDateTime {"format": "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}
```

dataweave function . I need to convert it to Oracle to_date format like this

```
to_date ('05/04/2021 16:49:03', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss').
```

I tried some dataweave functions but not meeting the expectations .

Comment: Can you share the DB column type? Is this a simple INSERT or an SP call?

Comment: Column type is Date in Oracle’s, but i need hours minutes and seconds as shown in question . Its a simple insert statement .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
now() as DateTime {"format": "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"} as String {"format": "dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss"}
```

Output:

```
"05/26/2021 22:26:52"
```

Comment: Why i am getting 46 in time
05/46/2021 18:46:50

Comment: now() as DateTime {"format": "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"} as String {"format": "dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss"}

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the answer as well.